# RESTful frameworks for Android, iOS...?

Tags: iphone, android, rest, restful-authentication, activeresource

My company is reworking its **API** and wants to make everything RIGHT for this time ;) **Thats the setup...**

- We are delivering data to clients over the internet.
- Clients are mobile handsets like iPhone, Androids, J2ME, Blackberry...
- The server is coded in Ruby on Rails

**We want to achieve through a framework...**

- Take use of ActiveResource on the clients.
- The framework should do the connection (REST), parsing and (dynamically) providing of models
- Licence must be open source.
- Authorization shall be included. We use OAuth and need to deliver the Access Token on any request. Maybe as parameter or in the HTTP-Header?
- HTTPS/SSL support
- Pagination and Relationships (with lazy loading) support would be great! Otherwize the framework must be able to be adjusted for these things.

**We already have found** following frameworks and kindly ask you guys to evaluate them. Maybe one of you used some of them or something different...

---

- Android: [RESTProvider from Novoda / Carl-Gustaf Harroch](http://www.github.com/novoda/restprovider/)

  - Providers offer an abstraction from data sources on Android and the RESTProvider Automatically parses RESTful API responses into a Provider. RESTProvider is an implementation of all commonly re-implemented functionality when dealing with web services in Android. Users can seamlessly interface with any Web Service API which provides JSON or XML as a response. To query a RESTProvider in an activity a user need only specify an endpoint and then query an APIs RESTful functions. RESTProvider also handles all HTTP querying & caching.
  - Haven't found much documentation other than that
  - Provides caching as well
  - Release + Documentation is planned for early 2011

---

- iOS: http://iphoneonrails.com/

  - Lib for communication between iOS and Rails
  - RESTful and "ActiveResource"-based
  - includes XML/JSON Parser
  - free licence
  - pagination?, android?, lazy loading?

---

- Android: [Hand made approach with the use of cursors backed by a SQLLite DB](http://mgmblog.com/2008/11/25/android-ruby-on-rails-project-part-3-using-android-cursors/)

  - intended to be very performant and best practice of Android
  - uses cursors

---

- Android: [Spring Android Rest Template Module](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html)

  - Spring's RestTemplate is a robust, popular Java-based REST client. The Spring Android Rest Template Module provides a version of RestTemplate that works in an Android environment.

---

- Android: You always should take a look at [this video of Google IO 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) when thinking serious about REST

---

- Android: [Feed Framework](http://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/wiki/FeedFramework)

  - com.google.android.feeds
  - A collection of classes to help you build content providers. The framework is specially designed to help connect your application to Web APIs.

Comment: After quite a long time of evaluation, we decided to choose "Spring Android Rest Template Module" now.

Answer (score 11):

I am the author of the RESTProvider. Still very early stage so I would not recommend to use it in production. I have been using it on several projects which are in production but I adapted most the code to specific needs. I will try to get a public stable API by the end of the year.

In regards to reworking the API, I would suggest the following:

1. Use GZip compression
2. Use ETags for caching
3. Use standards with no modification (I saw cases where the naming changed from oauth_token to my_token which makes most library useless without modification) - OAuth/REST
4. Use creation/modified timestamp and remote ids for all objects in order to enable caching client side (SQLite conflict clauses):
   {"myobject": {"createdAt": xxxx, "rid": "hashvalue"}}
   4a. Use a good way to identify the object returned for user/activity/application: opensocial uses "application id" + "user id" + "activity id"
5. Prefer JSON over XML
6. Prefer simplicity (lowest depth possible)
7. Return the full object with the one to many relationship within that object:
   {"parent":....
    "has": {"full object not just the ID"}
   }
8. Don't return IDs only ( "category": [ 2,3,4] should be "category": [{"name": "testing", "id": 2},{"name": "production", "id": 3 }} )
9. Consider each call to be independent of each other (i.e. I should have enough information for call http://test.com/object.json to populate my views)

For documentation:
1. provide test servers
2. provide cUrl for testing
3. provide sample scripts in java/php/ruby etc...

That s all I can think for now. I might add ontop of this as I come with more suggestion.

Comment: Re point 8 (and general REST principals): Be sure that every 'thing' is uniquely identified and that it is accessible via a URL. The URL (UNIQUE resource locator) can be used as the objects ID.

Comment: hi, so is it stable enough yet, I am intending to use it in a project.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend taking a look at [RestKit for iOS](http://restkit.org/)

- High performance, threaded network layer with a simple API for request/responses
- Object mapping system for mapping remote payloads into local objects declaratively (including relationships)
- Integration with Core Data for providing a fast local cache of remote data with synchronization capabilities
- Support for generating a seed database from a series of JSON payloads
- Specific support for integrating with Ruby on Rails backends (RKRailsRouter)
- Apache licensed
- Used in production in a number of excellent apps (i.e. [Gate Guru](http://gateguruapp.com))

Comment: I am using RestKit for iOS in several of my projects. It always performs up to the expectation.

Comment: It does not look like restkit is being maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Spring RestTemplate choice. Here is link for SSL https calls. Hope this helps others. Was looking for this solution a long time.

http://www.makeurownrules.com/secure-rest-web-service-mobile-application-android.html