# Any standard format to describe time ranges as String? Want to use it for opening hours

Tags: datetime, time, standards, datetime-format

We want to use it for opening hours like...

- Mo 11:00-13:00
- Tue 9:00-18:00
- **Update** *Now required: Wed 8:00-11:30, Wed 12:00-17:00*

We have a Ruby based server and deliver JSON and XML to the clients. We follow the ActiveResource pattern, so that we can use [plug ins in our clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097686/restful-frameworks-for-android-ios)

That's our current proprietary approach:

```
"availabilities":[{"end_time":"00:00","weekdays":"0,1,2,3,4,5,6","start_time":"00:00"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cron format](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm) was designed specifically for this, including relative dates like "from midnight to 1 AM of the first Monday each month except December".

**Edit**: cron expressions for all examples:

```
* 11-12 * * mon
* 9-17 * * tue
* 8-10 * * wed
0-29 11 * * wed
* 12-16 * * wed
```

Comment: That seems to be the right thing for us. Thx! Now we look for JAVA and Objective-C libraries to do the converting... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469276/convert-cron-expression-into-nice-description-strings-is-there-a-library-for-jav

Comment: SORRY! I had to unmark your answer. Because cron expression can't describe "Wed 8:00-11:30, Wed 12:00-17:00" because they separate minutes and hours. You just can say 0-30 8-11,12-17 * * Wed * which means "8:00-8:30,9:00-9:30,..." AND describing the 3 example entries in my question in one cron expression isn'T supported either ;(

Comment: @OneWorld, you need more than one expression, this is allowed in cron.

Comment: Ok. Could u provide me an example, how to code the example from my question?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the number of milliseconds since midnight. That's fairly standard, as in JavaScript and other languages you can easily add a number of milliseconds to a given time in order to get another time, or create a time-span object from a number of milliseconds.