# ContentProvider with WebService as source

Tags: android, google-maps, android-contentprovider, point-of-interest

The scenario is the following:

- I've got an android app that basically consists of a mapview.
- This app queries various web services such as Foursquare or Wikipedia to obtain a list of locations and plot them into the map.

The question,

- Does anybody know how to build a Content Provider where the data source is a web service (like the ones mentioned above) and not a db? It'd be great if you could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I just want to do the same, but instead of directly querying the web service it'd be the content provider the one doing it. In this way, I could use external apps to connect to different web services.

Comment: More options of ContentProviders to web services are mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097686/restful-frameworks-for-android-ios

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing as you were and i got across DataDroid [http://www.datadroidlib.com/](http://www.datadroidlib.com/presentation). I think it's easier to use and it's a straightforward way to handle REST if your webservice is REST oriented.

**Edit:**

DataDroid is now marked as deprecated. They move to Robospice see https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice

Answer (score 1):

> *Does anybody know how to build a Content Provider where the data source is a web service (like the ones mentioned above) and not a db?*

Take into account the following answer may be considered a rather old-fashioned 'manual' method.

You could build a content provider that *queries* the web service, and converts the obtained result into a *cursor*.

To query the web service you could use [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) and [HttpGet](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) request. You can find a tutorial on [MyKong](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/) on how to do this. There are also some [newer alternatives](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) to do this.

While parsing the search result you get from the web service, you can build your own cursor with the [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) class by adding rows with *addRow()* for every individual result.

If you were to do this, make sure you *always* call your Content Provider through a background thread (i.e. using [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html), [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads), or another form of threading), otherwise your network operation would end up on the main UI thread.